# AWS EB deployment issue "Failed to run npm install"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app to EB. The problem is, I'm getting the error on my EB dashboard, "Update environment operation is complete, but with errors.", and my app isn't running.

So I fetched the error log for my instance:

```
        i-0d5cffacd74ddf4dc Severe  5 hours 2   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0.00    0.00    0.0 0.0 100 0.0
Application deployment failed at 2017-11-26T17:43:27Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed.

+ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
npm WARN lifecycle node@9.2.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) node@9.2.0 node installArchSpecificPackage /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/.staging/node-2356d873
Portfolio@0.0.1 /tmp/deployment/application
├─┬ body-parser@1.18.2 
│ ├── bytes@3.0.0 
│ ├── content-type@1.0.4 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
│ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
│ ├── depd@1.1.1 
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.2 
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 
│ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.0.3 
│ │ └── statuses@1.4.0 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.19 
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
│ ├── qs@6.5.1 
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.3.2 
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.15 
│ ├── media-typer@0.3.0 
│ └─┬ mime-types@2.1.17 
│ └── mime-db@1.30.0 
├─┬ express@4.16.2 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.4 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.2 
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1 
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
│ ├── etag@1.8.1 
│ ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.0 
│ │ └── statuses@1.3.1 
│ ├── fresh@0.5.2 
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
│ ├── methods@1.1.2 
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.2 
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@2.0.2 
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.2 
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.5.2 
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
│ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
│ ├─┬ send@0.16.1 
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
│ │ ├── mime@1.4.1 
│ │ └── statuses@1.3.1 
│ ├── serve-static@1.13.1 
│ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.0 
│ ├── statuses@1.3.1 
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.1 
│ └── vary@1.1.2 
└── nodemailer@4.4.0 

npm ERR! Linux 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node/bin/node
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node/bin/node'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node/bin/node'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log
Running npm install: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm
Setting npm config jobs to 1
npm config jobs set to 1
Running npm with --production flag
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 254.
Incorrect application version "Deploy5" (deployment 2). Expected version "Deploy06" (deployment 3).
```

In the midst of it all, I find `Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.` Why does this happen? My app runs perfectly fine locally - why can't it run on aws?

File structure:
.zip

- node_modules/
- public/
- app.js
- package.json

Comment: Your really going to need to provide more info here.   Looking at your logs, things are a bit strange.   It's trying to run node from your tmp deployment directory:  /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node/bin/node, and it's saying that cannot be found.    In a node based app, then node should be installed at the server level, and you'd be using that node install.

Comment: My app is very basic. It is a one page site with a form that sends data through nodemailer. I updated my question with my file structure, is there anything else I could provide?